# Numpy concatenate void binary buffers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
a = [void(b'\x0A\x00\x01\x02'),
     void(b'\x0B\x02\x03\x04'),
     void(b'\x0C\x07\x03\x04')
    ]
```

I want something like
b'\x0A\x00\x01\x02\x0B\x02\x03\x04\x0C\x07\x03\x04'

Right now I am doing it using loop

```
result = bytearray()
for b in a:
   result += bytearray(b)
```

Is there any numpy kind of way to do it, so that it becomes fast.

Comment: `b''.join(bytearray)` works with ists and array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with numpy arrays, the easiest would probably be to call the `tobytes()` method.

```
from numpy import void 

a = [void(b'\x0A\x00\x01\x02'),
     void(b'\x0B\x02\x03\x04'),
     void(b'\x0C\x07\x03\x04')
    ]

np.array(a).tobytes()
```

Output:

```
b'\n\x00\x01\x02\x0b\x02\x03\x04\x0c\x07\x03\x04'
```